# In RVIZ, why does the aspect ratio with the top-down view change after a selection

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In RVIZ, with the top-down view, the user can resize the window to any format, and the aspect ratio stays constant (i.e. the squares of the grid are always squares). However, after the user tried to select something, the aspect ratio becomes variables. For example, if the window is 1000 X 500, the grid cells are squeezed and they are displayed twice as large as their height.

Why is that? How can I get rid of this behaviour?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9317/in-rviz,-why-does-the-aspect-ratio-with-the-top-down-view-change-after-a-selection/) by [Benoit Larochelle](https://answers.ros.org/users/216/benoit-larochelle/) on ROS Answers with karma: 867 on 2011-03-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is definitely a bug.  I've opened this ticket https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/4858 about it.

---

Originally posted by [hersh](https://answers.ros.org/users/97/hersh/) with karma: 1351 on 2011-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Fixed in trunk.  To check out and build the latest version, do:

svn co https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/visualization/trunk/rviz
cd rviz
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=`pwd`:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
rosmake

---

Originally posted by [hersh](https://answers.ros.org/users/97/hersh/) with karma: 1351 on 2011-03-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1